# Construct a functor by it's composition with the forgetful functor

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be any category. Consider a functor $F:\mathcal{C}\longrightarrow \mathbf{Grp}$ and take the composition with the forgetful functor $U:\mathbf{Grp}\longrightarrow \mathbf{Set}$. How to construct $F$ from $U\circ F$?

Any reference is well accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you think this is possible? Let $\mathcal{C} = \mathbf{1}$. Any functor $\mathbf{1}\to\mathbf{Grp}$ will just be a group, i.e. there is a correspondence between groups and functors $\mathbf{1}\to\mathbf{Grp}$. (Generally, there is a correspondence between objects of a category and functors from $\mathbf{1}$ into that category.) Let $F : \mathbf{1}\to\mathbf{Grp}$ be $F(1) = \mathbb{Z}_4$. Then $U \circ F$ is essentially a four element set, but there are two groups (up to isomorphism) on a four element set, and there's no way to know which of the two groups it is just given the set.

Answer (score 2):

This can't be done in general.  For instance, if $\mathcal{C}$ has just one object and one morphism, then $F$ consists of picking a group to send the one object to, while $U\circ F$ only knows the underlying set of the group.  You can't determine a group (even up to isomorphism) just from knowing its underlying set (at least in most cases).